# Having trouble linking css to bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am rather new to web dev, and am having trouble determining what is wrong with my code. I'm trying to customise bootstrap with my own css, yet it doesnt seem to be linking correctly? I tried changing something as simple as the background-color to the body which didn't work. Ive attached an image of my project below

[image: here]

Am I linking it incorrectly? Help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Image of CSS
[image]

Edit 2:

Apparently I forgot to add "@import UTF-8;" to the CSS sheet, which seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks everyone.

Comment: show us code of `custom.css`

Comment: added it to the OP

Comment: Looks like you didn't save your file

Comment: Your linking is fine, there might be a case of wrong attribute usage here, share your css file as well for after that.
Here is a link for some of the attributes of css - "https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp"
Might help :)

Comment: you are linking it correctly

Comment: add the code otherwise it's impossible to determine what's wrong...your linking looks ok

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem isn't the file linking. If bootstrap is loading on your project, that isn't the problem, but relative path isn't recommended. Instead, try to use absolute url path.

Maybe the problem is the css rule you are using. if your rule can't ovveride the bootstrap rule, it will not work. Example

A.css

```
.container > .item{
    background: red;
}
```

B.css

```
.item{
    background: blue;
}
```

example http://codepen.io/maxjf1/pen/qrNNpE

post the css and the html you are having problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your custom.css before bootstrap.css. Cutrently, in case of having some common classes, the classes of bootstrap are considered.